# How can I fake request.POST and GET params for unit testing in Flask?

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I would like to fake request parameters for unit testing. How can I achieve this in Flask?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Did you read [Flask docs about testing](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/testing/#faking-resources-and-context)?

You can use following:

```
self.app.post('/path-to-request', data=dict(var1='data1', var2='data2', ...))
self.app.get('/path-to-request', query_string=dict(arg1='data1', arg2='data2', ...))
```

Current development version of Flask also includes support for [testing JSON APIs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/testing/#testing-json-apis):

```
from flask import request, jsonify

@app.route('/jsonapi')
def auth():
    json_data = request.get_json()
    attribute = json_data['attr']
    return jsonify(resp=generate_response(attribute))

with app.test_client() as c:
    rv = c.post('/jsonapi', json={
        'attr': 'value', 'other': 'data'
    })
    json_data = rv.get_json()
    assert generate_response(email, json_data['resp'])
```

Comment: So, .get just expects you to add the params at the end of the query, like so -- `?param1=value&param2=value2` -- or can it receive a dict as well?

Comment: I've tried both, only the first option worked. Why do you ask?

Comment: @ssilver you can use a dict but its not called data like .post :  self.app.get('/endpoint', query_string=params)

Comment: Thanks for a constructive answer, @jskulski -- it just helped me as well. Trying something out tells you what doesn't work, but it doesn't tell you if there's a different way that does work.

Comment: how do you pass a json as input?

Comment: cant we just do the following: response = app.post('/path-to-request', json=data) ,  
  self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)

Comment: additionally, should I launch the app before running the unit tests?

Comment: @LoveMeow No, you need to set up app context.

Answer (score 44):

POST:

```
self.app.post('/endpoint', data=params)
```

GET:

```
self.app.get('/endpoint', query_string=params)
```

Answer (score 6):

If you prefer to use `test_request_context`:

```py
import unittest
from myapp import extract_query_params

testapp = flask.Flask(__name__)

class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_happy(self):
        with testapp.test_request_context('?limit=1&offset=2'):
            limit, offset = extract_query_params(['limit', 'offset'])
            self.assertEquals(limit, 1)
            self.assertEquals(offset, 2)
```

Comment: `with testapp.test_request_context(headers=h):` can be used to pass **headers** without mentioning any **url**, this will mock a request with _default-url_

Answer (score 3):

I needed an simple request for unit testing, and this was an easy solution:

```
from flask import Request
r = Request({})
```

Answer (score 1):

I still had issue with this when testing post form data for logging in this worked for me.

```
def login(self, username, password):
    return self.app.post('/', data='Client_id=' + username +'&Password=' + password,
                         follow_redirects=True,content_type='application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
```

I found this is out this way.

Chrome:
    Developer mode --> Doc --> HTML doc that was requested --> Headers Tab --> Form data --> view source

Comment: `urllib.urlencode(form_data_dict)` or `urllib.parse.encode` in py3 is useful to create `data` from the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

here is a complete code example of a unit test

```
testapp = app.test_client()

class Test_test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_user_registration_bad_password_short(self):
        response = self.register(name='pat',
                                 email='me@mail.com', 
                                 password='Flask', 
                                 password2='Flask')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertIn(b'password should be 8 or more characters long', 
                      response.data)

    def register(self, name, email, password, password2):
        return testapp.post(
            '/register',
            data=dict(username=name, 
                      email=email, 
                      password=password, 
                      password2=password2),
            follow_redirects=True
        )
```

Comment: this gives `*** AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'status_code'`